# TCP connection between NodeJS server and endpoint (TV)

Tags: node.js, tcp

I want to use NodeJS to communicate with a TV(external device on LAN - wireless) to send and receive RS232 serial commands.

I tried http, net, express, serialport, all of the modules that I can think of that would be of any assistance to my project. However, I was not able to achieve connection.

I realize that it is the client that is suppose to initiate the connection, however, what I want to do is check if the TV is on, or tell the TV to turn off/on using NodeJS.

How can I achieve this?

I have experience with JavaScript but fairly new to NodeJS. I have looked at many tutorials, APIs, and NodeJS website, but I can't seem to figure out it.

Comment: What is the relation between the network and the serial connection?

Comment: So I am trying to send serial commands via network

Comment: There is no such thing as "serial command". Both rs,232 is a physical and mefia accesd level protocol over serial line. Just like the ethernet stack. You can send anything over both. You can interact with a networked device over the services it provides. If it exposes no service that will accept your commands, then you can't. It might expose undocmented services though. So, everything depends on your device manufacturer. You can try nmap to find out open ports. It can try to guesd services also. What is the tv's exact type?

Comment: In that case, am I sending requests to the TV as a NodeJS server? And would it be different services for different manufacturers?

Comment: _Supposing_ it has a network server functionality implemented you can connect to it - yes. But the port, the protocol csn be anything...

Comment: Regardless of the manufacturer, can I start with something(http request or sockets or other), or you are saying it all depends?

Comment: Start with discovering open ports using NMAP.

Comment: For some reason, I am not able to use NMAP....

Comment: Ok, then I can't guide you further. I cannot handle "some reason".

Comment: Okay. So, this is what I get from nmap -T4 -A -v -Pn 1-65535 192.168.10.182 ==> Initiating ARP Ping Scan at 16:12
Scanning 192.168.10.182 [1 port]
Completed ARP Ping Scan at 16:12, 0.42s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.10.182 [host down]
Initiating SYN Stealth Scan at 16:12
Scanning 1-65535 (92.242.140.21) [1000 ports]
Discovered open port 80/tcp on 92.242.140.21
Increasing send delay for 92.242.140.21 from 0 to 5 due to 11 out of 14 dropped probes since last increase.

Comment: There are two ip addresses. Whic one is the tv? What is the manufacturer and the type of the tv?

Comment: Actually the result is as follows: PORT:80, protocol: tcp, state:open, service:http, version:lighttpd; PORT:1024, protocol: tcp, state:open, service:kdm. I am currently working with Panasonic LFE8